# Analyse GPS data in R

Tags: r, gps, latitude-longitude

I need to analyse a large dataset of GPS recordings in R. I am aiming to be able to track movements of organisms including individual territory size and dispersion. I have been told that it is possible to use R rather than GIS programs for this, however I have no idea how to go about it. I have GPS readings in Latitude and Longitude (40510186N 005169210W) as well as decimal latitude and longitude (40.85031 -5.282017) as well as a whole bunch of other variables. Are there any packages that I could install that would be usefull in processing this data? Any suggestions on how I should proceed with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the data. You can show dots on a map very easily with a few packages. What does "processing" the data mean to you?

Comment: Showing dots on a map would be good. I will also need to be able to track how far individuals range (probably in kilometers) so that I can measure the average territory size from a nest site and how far juveniles disperse from their parent's territory. I also have a timestamp for each GPS signature so a way of being able to track movement over time would be really useful, especially if it could be shown on a map. Is there a way R could sequentially read the timestamps and calculate the distance in km between each time stamp's GPS signature and the next?